# How to limit file types on file uploads for ModelForms with FileFields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

My goal is to limit a FileField on a Django ModelForm to PDFs and Word Documents. The answers I have googled all deal with creating a separate file handler, but I am not sure how to do so in the context of a ModelForm. Is there a setting in settings.py I may use to limit upload file types?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I handle this by using a clean_[your_field] method on a ModelForm. You could set a list of acceptable file extensions in settings.py to check against in your clean method, but there's nothing built-into settings.py to limit upload types.

Django-Filebrowser, for example, takes the approach of creating a list of acceptable file extensions in settings.py.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution does little to prevent someone from adding a .doc or .pdf to the end of the file in order to upload it.  Checking an extension - in general - isn't a good way to guarantee that a file is of a particular type.

Answer (score 52):

Create a validation method like:

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('.pdf'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Error message')
```

and include it on the FileField validators like this:

```
actual_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_files', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

Also, instead of manually setting which extensions your model allows, you should create a list on your setting.py and iterate over it.

### Edit

To filter for multiple files:

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
  import os
  ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
  valid_extensions = ['.pdf','.doc','.docx']
  if not ext in valid_extensions:
    raise ValidationError(u'File not supported!')
```

Comment: how to create a list in  setting.py and iterate over it ?

Comment: This answer is one huge security vulnerability. User can add **anything** under filename with presumably valid extensions.

Comment: isn't the most 'django-esque' way to do this by using the `clean_[your field]' method on the model/form? Why would one prefer this method over the one suggested in Brandon's post?

Answer (score 36):

Validating with the extension of a file name is not a consistent way. For example I can rename a picture.jpg into a picture.pdf and the validation won't raise an error.

A better approach is to check the content_type of a file.

**Validation Method**

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    if value.file.content_type != 'application/pdf':
        raise ValidationError(u'Error message')
```

**Usage**

```
actual_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_files', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

Comment: The same is true for the content_type-field, as this is taken from the request, which can be chosen by the user as well. Both methods - extension and content_type - open easy attack vectors. The only half sure way is to check the file mimetype itself after uploading - and even that is not nearly save.

Answer (score 18):

An easier way of doing it is as below in your Form

```
file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'application/pdf'}))
```

Comment: This is great for usability on the frontend but doesn't actually control what gets uploaded.

Answer (score 11):

Django since 1.11 has a [FileExtensionValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator) for this purpose:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

class SomeDocument(Model):
    document = models.FileField(validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'doc'])])
```

As @savp mentioned, you will also want to customize the widget so that users can't select inappropriate files in the first place:

```
class SomeDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeDocument
        widgets = {'document': FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'application/pdf,application/msword'})}
        fields = '__all__'
```

You may need to fiddle with `accept` to figure out exactly what MIME types are needed for your purposes.

As others have mentioned, none of this will prevent someone from renaming `badstuff.exe` to `innocent.pdf` and uploading it through your form—you will still need to handle the uploaded file safely. Something like the [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) library can help you determine the actual file type once you have the contents.

Answer (score 6):

For a more generic use, I wrote a small class `ExtensionValidator` that extends Django's built-in `RegexValidator`. It accepts single or multiple extensions, as well as an optional custom error message.

```
class ExtensionValidator(RegexValidator):
    def __init__(self, extensions, message=None):
        if not hasattr(extensions, '__iter__'):
            extensions = [extensions]
        regex = '\.(%s)$' % '|'.join(extensions)
        if message is None:
            message = 'File type not supported. Accepted types are: %s.' % ', '.join(extensions)
        super(ExtensionValidator, self).__init__(regex, message)

    def __call__(self, value):
        super(ExtensionValidator, self).__call__(value.name)
```

Now you can define a validator inline with the field, e.g.:

```
my_file = models.FileField('My file', validators=[ExtensionValidator(['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'])])
```

Comment: This is great - the only part I can't get to work is `if message is None:
            message = 'File type not supported. Accepted types are: %s.' % ', '.join(extensions)` - the functionality works but I don't get an error message.  Prolly something I'm doing wrong!

Comment: I was advised to move away from using a custom class so I'm not pursuing this anymore.  Thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 5):

I use something along these lines (note, "pip install filemagic" is required for this...):

```
import magic
def validate_mime_type(value):
    supported_types=['application/pdf',]
    with magic.Magic(flags=magic.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE) as m:
        mime_type=m.id_buffer(value.file.read(1024))
        value.file.seek(0)
    if mime_type not in supported_types:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file type.')
```

You could probably also incorporate the previous examples into this - for example also check the extension/uploaded type (which might be faster as a primary check than magic.)  This still isn't foolproof - but it's better, since it relies more on data *in* the file, rather than browser provided headers.

Note: This is a validator function that you'd want to add to the list of validators for the FileField model.

Comment: I have a problem with this because in my website some people are trying to upload files up to 200MB sometimes, and my server doesn't have much memory, so it's throwing a 500 when it can't allocate the memory. We're a small startup and are avoiding as much as possible spending more money, so I was wondering if there's a way to check the file while divided in separate parts, or without reallocating the whole file in the server. TY :)

Answer (score 1):

I find that the best way to check the type of a file is by checking its content type. I will also add that one the best place to do type checking is in form validation. I would have a form and a validation as follows:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_file(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['file']

        # check if the content type is what we expect
        content_type = data.content_type
        if content_type == 'application/pdf':
            return data
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid content type'))
```

The following documentation links can be helpful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/uploads/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score 0):

After conducting some research, I have integrated various tips provided here. To address the issue, I implemented a solution using a third-party library named [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/). Instead of solely validating file extensions, which can be easily manipulated by users changing the file extension, we now verify the content's [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).

To implement this, first, define a widget that appends the necessary attributes to your form input. If you're using a model form, include this widget in your form. Otherwise, directly add it to your HTML.

```py
from django import forms

from .models import YourModel


class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ["file_field"]
        widgets = {
            "file_field": forms.FileInput(attrs={"accept": "video/mp4"})
        }
```

This approach suggests users upload a specific type of video, but it's important to note that this is currently a front-end validation only. To enhance security, you should implement back-end validation.

Call the [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean) method, which is executed when is_valid() is triggered, to perform actual validation in your code. This ensures a more robust validation process beyond the front-end checks.

```py
from django import forms
import magic

from .models import YourModel

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ["file_field"]
        widgets = {
            "file_field": forms.FileInput(attrs={"accept": "video/mp4"})
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        file_field = cleaned_data.get("file_field")

        if file_field:
            file_type = magic.from_buffer(video_file.read(), mime=True)

            if file_type != "video/mp4":
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Unsupported file type. Only mp4 videos are allowed."
                )

            file_field.seek(0)

        return cleaned_data
```

And is it, now you must have full validation using python-magic, modelForm and clean method