# How to check the extension of uploaded file?

Tags: django

I only want .xlsm files to be uploadable to the form.

This my field in models.py

```
...
pdf = models.FileField( upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator), you just have to do this:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
    
class YourModel(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['xlsm'])])
```

This just checks the file ending and validates it ends in .xlsm, and if it doesn't it raises a [ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ValidationError).

There are many ways of doing this, here are some resources I found on stack overflow:

- [Validating upload file type in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172396/validating-upload-file-type-in-django)
- [Django: Validate file type of uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272579/django-validate-file-type-of-uploaded-file)
- [Django - Uploaded file type validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741001/django-uploaded-file-type-validation)

Next time, try searching for answers to your question before going on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Django Upload Validator is one option for handling that:
https://pypi.org/project/django-upload-validator/

Comment: I think you don't need an external python package for this, since you could just take the file extension and then validate it is an xlsm file. Although maybe I am wrong.

Comment: There is indeed more than one way to solve this problem. We don't need to scold people for providing different answers or for asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to check the extension of the file before saving the model using the clean() method like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError # for returnig errors
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import re # import regex python module

class PdfModel(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField( upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        pattern = re.compile('.*\.xlsm$')
        
        if not pattern.search(self.pdf):
            raise ValidationError(_('Only .xlsm files are accepted'))
```

more information about clean() method [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

Comment: There is an error: expected string or bytes-like object