# Why Django model extesion validator doesn't work

Tags: django

I want to only .xlsm files to be uploadable to the form.I tried a lot of thing according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713167/how-to-check-the-extension-of-uploaded-file?noredirect=1#comment121439932_68713167). But did not work. I don't know why? How can I solve it?

**models.py**

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
...
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['xlsm'])])

...
```

When I add this to my model :

```
def clean(self):
    pattern = re.compile('.*/.xlsm$')

    if not pattern.search(self.pdf):
        raise ValidationError(_('Only .xlsm files are accepted'))
```

I get an error:

> expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Did you try to run the validators in forms.py?

Comment: the field definition in model is enough for your goal. Why you are doing extra validation in `clean` method?

Comment: Cause of the error is `self.pdf` I think. At the time `clean` method invoked `self.pdf` is blank or null

Comment: @David I did nothing in forms. What should I do?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov I tried both of them seperately

Comment: @edche try to add breakpoint to you `clean` method and look at the value of `self.pdf`