# Django how to use validate_image_file_extension

Tags: django, django-models

hello how to pass a validator on model field ? how to validate dhe field?

from django.core.validators import validate_image_file_extension

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=image_upload_path, validators=?????)
```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27916582/1999801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use **validate_image_file_extension** you need to import it from **django.core.validators**, then you can use it like others [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/):

```
from django.core.validators import validate_image_file_extension

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=image_upload_path, validators=[validate_image_file_extension])
```

If a user uploads a file that isn't an image, you will see this message in the error list:

```
Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.
```

To get the error list in the template you have to use this:

```
{{ form.image.errors }}
```

Where form is the form object passed to the template.

Comment: Is it possible to override or translate the error message? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Nevermind I made it work! I added an if statement in the view for `image.errors['image']` and redirected with a message.