# How to restrict users to upload only doc and pdf formats in FileField in django?

Tags: django

I am working on a tutors website so tutors have to upload their resumes So I want to restrict them to upload only doc or pdf format resume through FileField in Django Models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Django, how does one limit file types on file uploads for ModelForms with FileFields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460848/in-django-how-does-one-limit-file-types-on-file-uploads-for-modelforms-with-fil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
        import os
        ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
        valid_extensions = ['.pdf','.doc','.docx']
        if not ext in valid_extensions:
            raise ValidationError(u'File not supported!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions:

[ExtFileField](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/977/)

[python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)