# Django: Restrict file type on MULTIPLE uploads

Tags: python, django, filefield, multiple-file-upload

I'm still new to Django and have found some [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272579/django-validate-file-type-of-uploaded-file) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460848/how-to-limit-file-types-on-file-uploads-for-modelforms-with-filefields) on how to restrict the type of file uploaded through Django's FileField. However, these answers deal with the case of a single file upload. I am dealing with the case of a multiple file upload, like so:

**forms.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    def clean_docfile(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data["docfile"]

        if not file.name.endswith('.txt'):
            raise ValidationError(u'Error: Text files only.')

        return file

    docfile = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
                              label='Select some files'
                              )
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from myproject.myapp.validators import validate_file_extension

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path, validators = [validate_file_extension])
```

**validators.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_file_extension(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('.txt'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Error: Text files only.')
```

I want the user to be able to upload multiple files at one time, but have all files rejected if at least one file is the incorrect file type.

Currently, clean_docfile only seems to check the name of the file that appears last alphabetically. So, the file selection [A.txt, B.txt, C.png] does not upload (as intended), but [A.txt, B.png, C.txt] does upload (when it shouldn't). When I look at the value of the object self.cleaned_data["docfile"] within my clean_docfile function, it appears to only store the attributes of the file that appears last alphabetically. How do I recover all of the uploaded file names?

Comment: The code above does not filter the file type, it only filters the file name extension. That's not the same and not sufficient when security is a topic.