# Restrict file upload to only audio and video formats

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I add audio and video file fields in Django which accepts only the particular files?

Kindly explain me with 1 example.

**models.py**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to = u'mp3/', max_length=200)
     video_file = models.FileField(upload_to = u'video/', max_length=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
     audio_file = forms.FileField( label = _(u"Audio File" ))
     video_file = forms.FileField( label = _(u"Video File" ))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply check it through Form's `clean` method

```
class FileUploadForm( forms.Form ):
    audio_file = forms.FileField( label = _(u"Audio File" ))
    ...

def clean( self ): 
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    file = cleaned_data.get( "audio_file" )
    file_exts = ('.mp3', ) 

    if file is None:

        raise forms.ValidationError( 'Please select file first ' ) 

    if not file.content_type in settings.UPLOAD_AUDIO_TYPE: #UPLOAD_AUDIO_TYPE contains mime types of required file

        raise forms.ValidationError( 'Audio accepted only in: %s' % ' '.join( file_exts ) ) 


    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 2):

May be these links will help you:

[Only accept a certain file type in FileField, server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects