# Is there a way to only allow for images to be uploaded when using django-multiupload?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-uploads

as the title says, is there a way to only allow for images to be uploaded when using django-multiupload? At the moment my users can upload any file but I want to limit them to only images.
Any help/advice would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a check to the validate function in the source code to only accept files with image extensions. I'm not 100% sure but that should work, take a look at the answer here [Only accept a certain file type in FileField, server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield)

especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27081099/1306336

Answer (score -1):

Have a fast look a the source code. No, it doesn't provide a support for that.