# how to allow svg in django 3.0 in models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I want to upload the svg images from admin models, how I can enable it? or allowed specific extensions like other .webp ,.docx and pdf etc.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! Please let me know me if there is anything else I can help you with.

Comment: No thanks if worked there are some other issues i am facing but i think its part of the game :) so i am trying .

Comment: Great start for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, whenever you want your users to upload an image, then you should use the `models.ImageField()` in the corresponding model. For other types of media, you can use the `models.FileField()`, and you can create a custom validator to check if you want a .docx or .pdf, etc.

Create a `validators.py` file inside your app folder, and add the function:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import os

def validate_file_extension(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path & filename
    valid_extensions = ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx', '.jpg', '.png', '.xlsx', '.xls'] # populate with the extensions that you allow / want
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError('Unsupported file extension.')
```

Then in your `models.py`:

```
from .validators import validate_file_extension
```

And finally, use the validator for your model field:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/", validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

See also:

- [Only accept a certain file type in FileField, server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield-server-side)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/
- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html