# how to compress uploaded files in django using 7zip subprocess.call method?

Tags: python-3.x, django, file, compression, 7zip

im trying to compress uploaded files in django using 7zip.

i have successfully implemented compression and decompression of files using 7zip in python but i am not able to figure out how to integrate the same with django uploaded file so that whenever a file is uploaded ,a 7zp format for the same file is create and stored in the disk.

Code used in python for compression :

```
import subprocess
from py7zr import unpack_7zarchive
import shutil

exe = r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"
source = r"C:\profiles\Living in the Light_ A guide to personal transformation.pdf"
target = r"C:\profiles\Living1.7z"

def compress(source,traget):
    subprocess.call(exe + " a -t7z \"" + target + "\" \"" + source + "\" -mx=9")
    print('file compressed')

def uncompress(target):
    shutil.register_unpack_format('7zip', ['.7z'], unpack_7zarchive)
    shutil.unpack_archive(target, r'C:\Users\098an\Pictures\Camera Roll')
    print('file uncompressed')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are Django-specific tools that you must use other than 7-zip. One problem using 7-zip on the web is that, if the client's computer doesn't have it installed, your server won't run correctly.

I know two ways to work this out: if you are simply looking to compress images, you can refer to [this dev.to article](https://dev.to/gajesh/compress-images-in-django-3la8) on compressing images specifically. The other way to work this out is requiring users to upload in the form of zip files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield-server-side/43540603), but change the file extensions to `.zip`, `.rar`, or whatever you deem necessary

**EDIT**

There are ways to automatically zip all types of files such as this [pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/django-compress-storage/), but I'm not sure how those will work out as it's not a mainstream package. If you want to conserve upload space, try [setting a size bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472422/django-file-upload-size-limit) instead.

Comment: i have to compress filefields such that user can upload any file format i.e. pdf,docx etc and its is automatically stored in disk as filename.zip.

Comment: i tried using pypi package but it alwasy give import error : from compress_field import ZipFileFieldImportError: cannot import name 'ZipFileField' from 'compress_field. Other than this, i want to compress the file to reduce the memory used.i dont want to put any limitation to the size of the file uploaded.

Comment: "I'm not sure how those will work out as it's not a mainstream package" that's where the problem starts. There aren't many people doing zip files since most of them just limit the upload size of a document. Plus you might need to decompress it which takes even more time.